# Adding column to pandas DataFrame with new keys

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python.

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

quandlApiKey = "XXX" # Can't write the real one because it is forbidden.

d = {}
closing_data = pd.DataFrame()

indexes = {
    'SCF/CME_SP1_FW' : 'Settle',
    'CHRIS/LIFFE_Z1' : 'Settle',
    'CHRIS/EUREX_FMEU1' : 'Settle'
}

for index in indexes.keys():
    d[index] = quandl.get(index, start_date="2013-12-31", end_date="2014-12-31", api_key=quandlApiKey)

for index in indexes.keys():
    closing_data[index] = d[index]['Settle']
```

In the first iteration (SCF/CME_SP1_FW) it saves the first column just fine and the keys of the rows are 31/12/2013, 02/01/2014, 03/01/2014 ...

The date 01/01/2014 is **intentionally** missing.

On the second iteration the for loop adds the second column, but although `d[index]['Settle']` had the date 01/01/2014 **a row wasn't added for it in `closing_data`**.

Is there a way to join the rows of all the columns (when a row is missing in one of the columns I would like to have a NaN or something similar).

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeScotty I just did. Thank you.